# A word to refer to people who are self-taught and/or start working without even going to university?

Tags: word-choice

These are some of the words I thought of:

- Entrepreneur
- Dropout
- Startup
- Auto-didact

Any suggestions?

Comment: See [what-would-you-call-a-person-who-is-not-a-student-but-takes-interest-in-exploring academic topics](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50579/)

Comment: Do you have more context? Otherwise you should use a thesaurus because this is too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Autodidact](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/autodidactic)** is the dictionary word.

> Autodidact: a self-taught person

Comment: The OP mentioned that already though

Comment: Yes, and out of the options OP "thought of", I clarified that "Autodidact" is the "dictionary" word.